# null pointer exception from toolbar when set to landscape

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-toolbar

The app and toolbar work fine in portrait mode but as soon as I set it to landscape mode the app crashes.

Here is the logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:94)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:87)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:77)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:96)
at maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5323)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3930)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my toolbar (tool_bar.xml)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my activity main

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

here is the line of code that throws the exception

```
// initialise and set toolbar as actionbar
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and

```
maxbleggi.afstudentplanner.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
```

is this line specifically

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Can you post your activity code?

Comment: well the only thing above the 2 lines I posted is the setContentView and super.onCreate. Everything below setSupportActionBar(toolbar); isn't ran because the program crashes on that line

Comment: Your toolbar seems to be null. Are you using different layouts for portrait and landscape?

Comment: fml. You're right. I had a layout-land resource file that's been untouched for months. I forgot it even existed. That was the problem. Thanks for the help. I wouldn't have noticed it otherwise